# Read in input text Yes/No Boolean from user to proceed the next step

Tags: java, boolean

I amm at my very beginning at java and just wanted to ask.
I want to ask the user to put Yes/No to a question and proceed to the next question. How do I do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sff {
    
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Hello There! We want to ask you some questions! but first: ");
        System.out.print("Enter your age: "); 
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
        
        int age = num;

        if( age == 12){
            System.out.println("Hello Dan, I know you very well! ");    
        }
        
        {
        
        System.out.println("First question: ");
        System.out.println("Do you exercise?(Yes/No) ");
        // how do i proceed from here??
```

Comment: What have you done by now?

Comment: @MichaelBistritzki Post that in the question. You can't expect anyone to read that in the comments. And if you have code, what's your question?

Comment: There is no need to assign the value captured by `int num` to the new `int age` variable so you can use that in your `if` statement. `if (num == 12) {...`. A `boolean` can only be `true` or `false` so I think it's best to just capture the yes/no in a `String` object and check what the user has choosen. Since you are checking age in your `if` you can remove `num` variable all together as `age` would be a more suitable name.

Comment: What's your problem? You don't know how to read a string from scanner? You dunno how to do a string comparison?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content ([under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Scanner` and get next line, then check if that line is yes or no then handle respectively.

In the example below, I used a while loop to keep asking them to input yes or no in case they enter something different like "maybe".

For example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Loop until they enter either yes or no.
while(true){
String line = in.nextLine();
    // Use this to check if it is yes or no
    if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
      // Process yes
      break;
    }else if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
      // Process no
      break;
    }else{
      // Tell them to enter yes or no since they entered something else.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
//import to use the Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack_Overflow_Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("First question: ");
    System.out.print("Do you exercise?(Yes/No) ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //get the user input and store it as a String
    String exerciseQuestion = in.nextLine();
    //check what the user said.
    if(exerciseQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        System.out.println("Dan does exercise");
        //do you code when he exercises
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Dan does not exercise");
        //do your not exercise code here
    }
    System.out.println("Ask your next question so on....");

  }//main
}//class
```

If you want to deal with answers other than `yes/no` you can use this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack_Overflow_Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("First question: ");
    System.out.print("Do you exercise?(Yes/No) ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String exerciseQuestion;
    while (true){
        //get the user input
        exerciseQuestion = in.nextLine();
        //check if user input is yes or no
        if((exerciseQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) || 
                     exerciseQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
            //if yes break and continue with your code
            break;
        else
            //else loop back to get user input until answer is yes/no
            System.out.println("Please answer with yes or no only");

    }//while . i.e answer not yes or no
    if(exerciseQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        System.out.println("Dan does exercise");
       //do your code
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Dan does not exercise");
        //do your not exercise code here
    }//else

  }//main
}//class
```

Comment: Can the down voter explain why the down vote, please?

Comment: Yes, something like this but what about if the user puts an input that is "yes" and not "Yes"? or this kind of stuff?

Comment: Check the new edit. Just use, `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`

Comment: I have also added in the edit, to deal with answers other than `yes/no.`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Can you please, mark it as answered if this is what you were looking for. I am not sure why someone down voted this answer.